# Как перекинуть базу с 1С в базу mysql на сервере?

Tags: 1с, mysql

Скажите пожалуйста как можно перекинуть содержимое базы с 1С в базу mysql на сервере? Или подскажите в какую сторону копать? Рад буду любой информации. Подскажите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант сделать экспорт в CommerceML2 а потом сформировать SQL из XML выгрузки,а вообще надо более раскрыто вопросы ставить.

Comment: Поступило предложение создать сайт с элементами интернет магазина,  но я в PHP и в MYSQL пока не особо силен, и работал только с уже созданными базами, и понятия не имею как производить миграцию из базы в базу. Вот и спрашиваю куда копать?

Comment: @Arty21, купите битрикс, выйдет дешевле.